# Trying to connect to a file in another folder, ../ doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: php, html, filepath

I'm trying to connect two files that are in separate folders within a parent folder.

I've used this code to try and go out of the current folder and into the other but it doesn't work.

```html
 <?php include('../database/db.php'); ?>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: What is your folder and sub folder structure?

Comment: app->controllers->users.php + app->database->db.php. Trying to connect users.php to db.php by coming out of controllers folder and into database folder. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

@Run_Script is right - but don't mix "Path" with "URL"

I use to define in a general include-File (e.g. config.php) a Global-Variable, and then reuse it on every include (but don't forget to include first your config.php)

```
# in your config.php
$GLOBALS['app_path'] = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/app/';

# in your files
include($GLOBALS['app_path'] . 'database/db.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with `include` statements and relative URLs recently, and this page hugely helped me: [Resolving PHP Relative Path Problem](https://yagudaev.com/posts/resolving-php-relative-path-problem/).

Instead of using a relative path with `../` notation, I used the following structure:

```php
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/folder1/folder2/file.html");
```

Or in your case, as I understand it:

```php
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/app/database/db.php");
```

Even the full URL (with `https://www.example.com`) wouldn't work, but using `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` solved the problem.

Hopefully it will help you as well!